# Absolute image position not work when screen resolution changes

Tags: html, css

I want to place an image on another background image but the problem when I change the resolution of the screen the image that i want to place on top of background image will change its position. I use the below code

```
       <div id="identification ">
            <div class="identification-image-1">
                <a href="form.html">
                    <img id="image-1" src="images/identification-1.png" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div>
                <a href="form.html">
                    <img src="images/identification-new.png" alt="" width="100%" /> 
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS code:

```
#identification {
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
}

.identification-image-1 {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 350px;
 }
```

Note 'images/identification-new.png' is the background image of width 100%.
The above code resolve my issue but when I change screen resolution the absolute position didn't work.

Comment: Try `top`/`left` instead of `margin-top`/`margin-left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your margins should be set as a percentage of the height and width of the container. When the screen resolution or the size of the browser window changes `.identification-image-1` will move relative to the container. As the background image is 100% of the container too everything will be in sync.

for example

```
.identification-image-1 {
position: absolute;
top: [your percentage];
left: [your percentage];
margin-left: [negative margin];
margin-top: [negative margin];
}
```

To centring an image using absolute positioning `left:50%` would shift the left edge to the centre of your browser. Using a negative margin of imgWidth/2 positions the centre of the image in the centre of the browser.

Comment: Could you please explain the last line 'if using a position of 50% the negative margin would be half the width of the image to ensure the image is centered.' by an example.